# tree search using recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a way to be able to search in an array, with nested arrays, a node with information. It can be seen as a tree

```
const data = [
  {
    id: '1-1',
    name: "Factory",
    children: [
      {
        id: '1-1-1',
        name: "Areas",
        children: [
          {                
            id: '1-1-1-1',
            name: "Sales",
            children: [
              {
                id: '1-1-1-1-1',
                name: "Bill Gates",
                children:[...]
              },
              ...
             ]
          },
          ...
         ]
       },
       ...
      ],
    },
    ...
   ]
```

If I wanted to find the node with name: Bill Gates

Try this function, but it does not work properly

```
const getElements = (treeData, text) => {
  return treeData.map(node => {
    const textMatch = node.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase());
    if (textMatch) {
      console.log(node);
      return node;
    } else {
      if (node.children) {
        return getElements(node.children, text)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

In deeper data like Bill Gates Node returns the entire TreeArray, but with all the data that does not contain the name Bill Gates as undefined

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use `.map` here, because you don't want a mutated array, you just want to find a node. Using a for loop gets the expected result:

```js
const data = [{
    id: '1-1',
    name: "Factory",
    children: [
      {
        id: '1-1-1',
        name: "Areas",
        children: [
          {                
            id: '1-1-1-1',
            name: "Sales",
            children: [
              {
                id: '1-1-1-1-1',
                name: "Bill Gates",
                children:[]
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
   ]
}];


const getElements = (treeData, text) => {
  for (let i=0, node = treeData[i]; node; i++) {
    const textMatch = node.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase());
    if (textMatch) {
      console.log(node);
      return node;
    } else if (node.children) {
      return getElements(node.children, text)
    }
  }
};

getElements(data, 'Bill Gates');
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I try use for loops but is was very slowly to match all the data.